# What are the the H2 delimiters for Table and Column Names?

Tags: sql, h2, quoted-identifier

I have a legacy DB with column names which have keywords in them - I want to transfer to H2 without having to rename anything.

What can I use with SQL syntax to delimit column and table names?

SQL Server uses `[]`, MySQL uses ``` `` ```, Oracle uses `""`, and what does H2 use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#quoted_name) H2 follows the SQL standard and uses `"` for quoted identifiers, e.g. `"ORDER"`